# Mistakes in Divi with php.ini

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem with DIVI and suport say I must increase the recommended value for better experience:

```
PHP 7.2 or  higher
max_execution_time 180
display_errors 0
```

My hosting support say I must create php.ini. I create and send on (I think) right place but only PHP version are increase. I still see:
"max_execution_time
30 - We recommend 120 for the best experience. Learn more.
display_errors
1 - We recommend 0 for the best experience. Learn more.
"

This its code from hosting suport:

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
magic_quotes_gpc=Off
max_input_vars=5000
suhosin.session.cryptua=Off
suhosin.session.encrypt=Off
suhosin.post.max_vars=7000
suhosin.request.max_vars=7000
suhosin.simulation=On
memory_limit=786M
upload_max_filesize=786M
max_file_uploads=786M
post_max_size=786M
eaccelerator.enable=0
memory_limit=786M
upload_max_filesize=786M
```

Can You tell me that code are correct?

Comment: Is this shared hosting?

Comment: I thinks so. Problem are solved: DIVI don't like a jQuery code when are replicated :D